# Checking two lists for equal items

Tags: c#

I'm using this code for checking if two `List<T>` are equal or not:

```
public static bool EqualsAll<T>(this IList<T> a, IList<T> b)
{
    if (a == null || b == null)
        return (a == null && b == null);

    if (a.Count != b.Count)
        return false;

    EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(a[i], b[i]))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now assume that I'm using this code for checking two big lists. Is this code efficient?

Comment: Is there a reason that no one here is suggesting Linq? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx

Comment: The only caveat is that you have to order the lists first but that should be done before comparing them anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Checking whether two lists are equal is naturally an O(n) operation. So yes, your code looks efficient.

Note that you could also replace your `for` loop with [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal(v=vs.100).ASPX)

```
public static bool EqualsAll<T>(this IList<T> a, IList<T> b)
{
    if (a == null || b == null)
        return (a == null && b == null);

    if (a.Count != b.Count)
        return false;

    return a.SequenceEqual(b);
}
```

If you take a look at [its implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,63644a881e976b52), you'll notice that it's very similar to yours. It *might* be just a tiny bit less efficient - so if performance is an issue here, measure both approaches, and then weigh readability/maintainability vs performance gains.

On a different note, I would rename the method to `SequenceEqual` and consider it a "specialization" of `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` for lists.

I would also consider throwing an exception if either argument is null.
This would be consistent with the BCL's own extension methods (`Select`, `Where`, `ToList`, `SequenceEqual`, `Any`, `All`, etc).

Comment: +1 nice review. SequenceEqual is very inefficient compared to a for loop though.

Comment: Since you're only using `Count`, which is part of `ICollection<T>`, I'd replace the parameters by `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Great observation!

Comment: Perhaps it'd be a good idea to suggest to MS to dynamically check for `ICollection<T>` in `SequenceEqual` for an early out. They do similar checks in other parts of LINQ.

Comment: @JohanLarsson The implementation of SequenceEqual appears to be as efficient as possible when working with IEnumerable's. It will perform badly if both sequences are almost equal (with an element toward the end being different) but I think you'll find the for loop will be about the same in this case.

Comment: @CodesInChaos or `IReadOnlyList<T>`. 
[We can write a pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx)

Comment: @craftworkgames A for loop is quite a bit faster than MoveNext et al. I wrote my comment since Sirwan asked about efficiency.

Comment: @JohanLarsson are you sure about that. It's quite a complicated topic. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1124753/1596973

Comment: @craftworkgames As I remembered it the compiler turned foreach into for loop for both arrays and lists but I trust skeet over my memory. I'll write a benchmark.

Comment: Should be interesting.

Comment: @craftworkgames Does [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KqjAIc) make sense as a benchmark? I expected the difference to be bigger.

Comment: @JohanLarsson 1000 iterations is very far from enough. Also, I wouldn't run benchmarks in dotnetfiddle. I'd build it myself in *release mode*, and run it without the debugger attached. I'd also warm up the VM before the actual test, and run only *one* test at a time - as in, start the app and test hypothesis 1, stop, change the code, start the app and test hypthesis 2. (Eric Lippert had a great series of blog posts named "C# Performance Benchmark Mistakes, Part One" but the website seems to be down :/)

Comment: Yeah, tried to edit my code about not trusting the fiddle and a remark about the warmup. Was too lazy to think of a way to do the warmup that would not be optimized away. 
You can play with n and times to get meaningful numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is efficient.

Why not expose an overload allowing the caller to pass in a comparer?

```
public static bool EqualsAll<T>(this IList<T> a, IList<T> b)
{
    return EqualsAll(a, b, null); // there is a slight performance gain in passing null here.
    // It is how it is done in other parts of the framework.
}

public static bool EqualsAll<T>(this IList<T> a, IList<T> b, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (a == null || b == null) // I agree with dcastro that throwing probably makes more sense here.
        return (a == null && b == null);

    if (a.Count != b.Count)
        return false;

    if (comparer == null)
        comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(a[i], b[i]))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit on how/why your code is an improvement?

Comment: Not sure what to say really, giving the caller an opportunity to pass in a comparer of choice feels natural given [how it is done in the framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,806).

Answer (score 2):

> I would also consider throwing an exception if either argument is null. This would be consistent with the BCL's own extension methods

I agree with this, but as an interesting side note as to *why* you want to throw exceptions consider the following test case.

```
IList<string> list1 = null;
IList<string> list2 = null;

Assert.IsTrue(list1.EqualsAll(list2));
```

This test would actually pass but it's certainly a very odd thing to do; considering calling a method on a null value wouldn't normally work. It just so happens extension methods behave differently in this regard.

Whenever you're working with null values consider the following definitions:

- not set
- invalid
- undefined
- not allocated
- not really a list

If you think about nulls in these terms it becomes clear that throwing an exception is the only logical thing to do.